# Wincrypt: Unable to decrypt file which was encrypted in C#. NTE_BAD_DATA at CryptDecrypt

Tags: c++, cryptography, encryption, cryptoapi

I am trying to decrypt a piece of a file with wincrypt and I cannot seem to make this function decrypt correctly.  The bytes are encrypted with the RC2 implementation in C# and I am supplying the same password and IV to both the encryption and decryption process (encrypted in C#, decrypted in c++).

All of my functions along the way are returning true until the final "CryptDecrypt" function.  Instead of me typing out any more, here is the function:

```
static char* DecryptMyFile(char *input, char *password, int size)
{
    HCRYPTPROV provider = NULL;

    if(CryptAcquireContext(&provider, NULL, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0))
    {printf("Context acquired.");}
    else
    {
        if (GetLastError() == NTE_BAD_KEYSET)
        {
        if(CryptAcquireContext(&provider, 0, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET))
            {printf("new key made.");}
            else
            {
                printf("Could not acquire context.");
            }
        }
        else
        {printf("Could not acquire context.");}
    }

    HCRYPTKEY key = NULL;
    HCRYPTHASH hash = NULL;

    if(CryptCreateHash(provider, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hash))
    {printf("empty hash created.");}
    else
    {printf("could not create hash.");}

    if(CryptHashData(hash, (BYTE *)password, strlen(password), 0))
    {printf("data buffer is added to hash.");}
    else
    {printf("error. could not add data buffer to hash.");}

    if(CryptDeriveKey(provider, CALG_RC2, hash, 0, &key)) 
    {printf("key derived.");}
    else
    {printf("Could not derive key.");}

    DWORD dwKeyLength = 128;

if(CryptSetKeyParam(key, KP_EFFECTIVE_KEYLEN, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&dwKeyLength), 0))
    {printf("success");}
    else
    {printf("failed.");}

    BYTE IV[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    if(CryptSetKeyParam(key, KP_IV, IV, 0))
    {printf("worked");}
    else
    {printf("faileD");}

    DWORD dwCount = size;
    BYTE *decrypted = new BYTE[dwCount + 1];

    memcpy(decrypted, input, dwCount);
    decrypted[dwCount] = 0;


    if(CryptDecrypt(key,0, true, 0, decrypted, &dwCount))
    {printf("succeeded");}
    else
    {printf("failed");}

return (char *)decrypted;
}
```

input is the data passed to the function, encrypted.  password is the same password used to encrypt the data in C#.  size is the size of the data while encrypted.
All of the above functions return true until CryptDecrypt, which I cannot seem to figure out why.  At the same time, I'm not sure how the CryptDecrypt function would possibly edit my "decrypted" variable, since I am not passing a reference of it.

Any help or advice onto why this is not working would be greatly appreciated.  This is my first endeavour with wincrypt and first time using C++ in years.

If it is of any more help, as well, this is my encryption (in C#):

```
 public static byte[] EncryptString(byte[] input, string password)
    {
        PasswordDeriveBytes pderiver = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, null);
        byte[] ivZeros = new byte[8];
        byte[] pbeKey = pderiver.CryptDeriveKey("RC2", "MD5", 128, ivZeros);

        RC2CryptoServiceProvider RC2 = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();

        //using an empty initialization vector for convenience.
        byte[] IV = new byte[8];
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = RC2.CreateEncryptor(pbeKey, IV);

        MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        csEncrypt.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
        csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

        return msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
```

I have confirmed that my hash value in C++ is identical to my key in C#, created by PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey

Comment: You're supposed to call GetLastError() to get the error code (NTE_BAD_DATA, NTE_BAD_KEY, NTE_BAD_LEN etc)

Comment: Correct.  And I did and got Bad Data as mine.

Answer (score 3):

First, as in my comment, use GetLastError() so you know *what* it failed. I'll assume that you get NTE_BAD_DATA, all the other errors are much more easier to deal with since they basically mean you missed some step int he API call sequence.

The typical reason why CryptDecrypt would fail with NTE_BAD_DATA would be that you're decrypting the last block of a block cypher (as you are) and the decrypted padding  bytes are incorrect. This can happen if the input is truncated (not all encrypted bytes were saved to the file) or if the key is incorrect.

I would suggest you take this methodically since there are so many places where this can fail that will all manifest only at CryptDecrypt time:

1. Ensure that the file you encrypt in C# can be decrypted in C#. This would eliminate any file save truncation issues.
2. Try to encrypt and decrypt with fixed hard codded key first (no password derived), this will ensure that your key set code IV initialization are correct (as well as padding mode and cypher chaining mode).
3. Ensure that the password derivation process arives at the same hash. Things like ANSI vs. Unicode or terminal 0 can wreak havok on the MD5 hash and result in wildly different keys from apparently the same password hash.

Comment: This sounds like a good battle plan, thank you.  How do you hard code the key for these?  My apologies for my ignorance.  I have not seen examples doing this and this is my first time doing this type of thing.

Comment: Is been a while... If I remember correctly, you use CryptImportKey to create a key handle from a known session key. Not sure how that works with RC2, never used it myself.

Comment: If that doesn't work, at least ensure the pass phrase hash matches before you derive the key (duplicate the md5 handle with CryptDuplicateHash, then extract the hashed value). Also see if the generated key's mathc, use CryptExportKey(... PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB) to extract the RC2 key in C++

Comment: I duplicated the hash and my original has a value of 2327592, while my dup has a value of 2358464.  I'm assuming this is an issue? This is directly after duplication

Comment: Also, incase I've misread, this is how I created the duplicate. HCRYPTHASH duphash = NULL;
 CryptDuplicateHash(hash, 0, 0, &duphash);

Comment: 2327592 looks like is the hash handle, ie. a pointer. You must extract the hash digest using CryptGetHashParam(... HP_HASHVAL) and compare it with the C# password phrase hash digest.

Comment: BYTE *mydata = new BYTE[512];
 DWORD mydatasize = 512;
 CryptGetHashParam(hash, HP_HASHVAL, mydata, &mydatasize, 0); looks plausible?  The size return was 16, which looks possibly reasonable.  However, the mydata returned was garbage data.

Comment: the garbage returned by CryptGetHashParam is equal between the original hash and the hash i have duplicated, however

Answer (score 1):

Some people have discovered issues when moving between operating systems.
The CryptDeriveKey call uses a "default key length" based on the operating system and algorithm chosen. For RC2, the default generated key length is 40 bits on Windows 2000 and 128 bits on Windows 2003. This results in a "BAD DATA" return code when the generated key is used in a CryptDecrypt call.

Presumably this is related to "garbage" appearing at the end of the final buffer after trying to apply a 128 bit key to decrypt a 40 bit encrypted stream. The error code typically indicates bad padding bytes - but the root cause may be a key generation issue.

To generate a 40 bit encryption key, use  ( ( 40 <<16 ) ) in the flags field of the CryptDeriveKey call.